# How do I prevent the screen from going blank?

Tags: debian, display, xorg

I am running the Debian wheezy beta and using my Pi to display my geckoboard dashboards using midori, as a result I want to prevent the screen from going blank, which it does after 10 minutes (though it doesn't seem to turn off the backlight). I have searched through the menu options and can not find how to prevent this. I came across a post on raspberrypi.org suggesting that the following:

```
sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -blank 0 >/dev/tty0"
```

would solve the problem, but it does not work. I have also tried changing `BLANK_TIME` to zero in `/etc/kbd/config` without success.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This is an `X` power-saving thing.

Firstly, you may need to install `xset`, a lightweight application that controls some `X` settings.

```
apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

Now open up your `~/.xinitrc` file (if you don't have one then create it) and enter this:

```
xset s off         # don't activate screensaver
xset -dpms         # disable DPMS (Energy Star) features.
xset s noblank     # don't blank the video device

exec /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager      # start lxde
```

This file runs once every time `X` starts and should solve the problem.
I copy and pasted it from my own `.xinitrc` and can confirm that my screen does not blank.

Comment: @SteveRobillard `apt-get install x11-xserver-utils`

Comment: Which account should the .xinitrc be created for? The pi account (which auto-logs in) or the root account (which owns the x-server)?

Comment: I created it for the pi account and it works OK! Thank you all.

Comment: what does `exec /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager` do?  When I take it out the bar at the bottom is gone.  I'm curious about how it all fits together.  A brief explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: @Scoop It just starts `lxde` with session management. This allows you to boot up with applications from your previous session still running. If you remove it `lxde` will start from a blank slate, which is why there is no toolbar (it's not been started).

Comment: Modifying: `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` as described here and modifying `~/.xinitrc` + `/etc/kbd/config` as described from `cwd` did not get me any further. My screen still gets black with backlight.

Comment: Can confirm this **does not work** on the Pi 3

Comment: This certainly didn't work on my Raspberry PI 2 Model B running Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: This doesn't work in the Debian Jessie (8) that I run with parallels VM in a MacBook Pro.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this worked for me on Pi 3 with the Lite image of Raspbian and `nodm` as the display manager. Only difference is that in my case the commands had to be put in the `~/.xsession`. I think the reason this solution doesn't appear to work for most people is related to `lightdm` specifically which is what most use.

Answer (score 28):

The other solutions here did not work for me (fresh Raspbian, **boot to GUI**). Instead, this worked:

1. Open up `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` using your favorite text editor (I prefer `nano`).
2. Look for the line `#xserver-command=X`. Change it to `xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms`

   - It should be at line 87 if things don't change.
3. Save and reboot.

[Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=185781#p185781)

Comment: This DID work on my Raspberry PI 2 Model B running Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: This worked for me on Pi3 with Jessie

Comment: I'm trying to understand these options. `-s 0` sets the screen timeout to 0 minutes, which I assume makes it 'never'. (Is this different from `-s off`?) Why `dpms`, though, not `-dpms`? Don't I want to _disable_ display power management services?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Have you tried this solution with `-dpms`? Please report back and maybe we can infer what's going on.

Comment: @pandalion98 Testing it right now with `dpms`, `-dpms`, and neither. Will report back soon.

Comment: I realized I'm not on a Pi here, so I don't know how general this is. That being said, `-s 0` appears to be all that's necessary on my system. Neither `dpms` nor `-dpms` appeared to have any effect.

Comment: This also worked for me on my Raspberry Pi 3.  Line number to change though was 91 now.

Comment: Using `-dpms` disables DPMS, while `+dpms` enables it.  Using just `dpms` also enables it, in practice, though "man xset" says it can be followed by up to three numbers (to set standby/suspend/off timeouts), or other options such as "force on" or "suspend".  See "man xset" for details.

FYI, with a Pi 3 and a Raspbian lite (Stretch/9.4) install to which I then added the GUI stuff, this answer worked for me, when using `-dpms`.

Answer (score 14):

I think @Jivings answer may be better, but I have it in my notes to do this:

- **Install** `apt-get install x11-xserver-utils`
- **Edit** `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`

**Append** these lines:

```
@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
```

Possibly also **comment out** the line that says `@xscreensaver -no-splash`, so the complete file should look something like this:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
# @xscreensaver -no-splash

@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
```

Also **edit** `/etc/kbd/config` and make sure these values are set as follows (however I believe this is only for when the lightweight desktop (LXDE) is *not* running (i.e. the `pi` is still in text / terminal mode):

```
BLANK_TIME=0
BLANK_DPMS=off
POWERDOWN_TIME=0
```

I believe that the `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` may be the sort of system-wide version of `~/.xinitrc` but someone else probably knows the nuances better.

Comment: Edits to /etc/kbd/config solved the problem for me.

Comment: I applied all the changes mentioned in this answer. This certainly didn't work on my Raspberry PI 2 Model B running Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: I think there has been some change with profiles by default, the autostart you need to edit might be `~/.config/lxprofile/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

Comment: my rpi 2 on raspbian jessie needed the above edits to `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` as jason points out below

Answer (score 10):

To prevent the screen from going blank try adding `consoleblank=0` to the end of the first line of `/boot/cmdline.txt`

[Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=889937&sid=c2b8232b30cda64ed4cdf94361658a30#p889937)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers for duplicate questions.

Comment: It was a very difficult answer to find and figured it applied.  Why not vote for this to be a duplicate question instead of commenting?

Comment: I voted for the original question to be marked as duplicate of this one. Keeping either of the answers sounds fine, but I suppose you prefer to have the one that got upvoted.

Comment: I wouldn't want my answer to only be on the duplicate, I would want it on the master of the two - even if I found the other question first.  Which is why i suggested you vote instead of comment

Comment: This is the only solution that has worked for my Pi Zero with a monitor but no keyboard, and no X11.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was editing `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and commenting out the screensaver, all the other `xset` commands didn't seem to affect it when it is started here:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
#@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

You might also need to add one or both of these lines to disable the power management:

```
@xset dpms 0 0 0
@xset -dpms
```

On the version of Raspbian Jessie I got the utils were already installed.