# Disable USB wifi sleep/suspend

Tags: linux

Whenever I leave my Raspberry Pi on overnight, it always seems to have entered some kind of suspended state. The red power light is still on but the light on the USB WiFi device is off and I can't access it with SSH.

I have no peripherals attached except for a USB WiFi device. I just use it headless as an audio player.

Anyone know how to completely disable any kind of suspend features?

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you could tag your question with the appropriate display manager. Thanks!

Comment: Can you see any output on an attached screen?
And do you have an up-to-date OS? Could be a kernel panic, which happended to me randomly after certain uptime.

Comment: @BryanDunsmore I doubt  he is using a DM - it's a ***headless*** audio player...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent the screen from going blank?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-do-i-prevent-the-screen-from-going-blank)

Comment: @AlexChamberlain If he is using Raspian I highly doubt he has uninstalled the default display manager. =/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I never got a notification that there were replies. As I said, "headless" and "no peripherals attached except for a USB WiFi device" so that means no monitor/screen. I'm using Raspian.

Comment: Although you are running headless, it still could possibly be running a display manager.  When you hook up a screen and boot it,  if it's truly headless it should only show a text based command prompt asking for login details.  I only ask because I'm running a bittorrent seed box on my Raspberry pi, and I've never experienced this. Also try plugging in an Ethernet cable next time it falls asleep. Perhaps it's something to do with the USB wifi adapter turning itself off for some reason.  Does the disk light still flash when it's "asleep"?

Comment: @dgrant I noticed you hadn't selected an answer on this, so I'm guessing your issue was not solved. Please take a look at my answer and see if it is of any help.

Comment: I had a similar problem with an ethernet connection. I ended up adding a script that retries getting an internet connection if it goes down. Seems to have helped.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You didn't provide a lot of details, but I'm going to assume you are using a WiFi adapter with the Realtek 8192cu chip, since that seems to be commonly used. Mine is the same and I have been experiencing what I think is the same issue: when leaving the RPi idle for an extended period of time, the WiFi seems to be disabled and you can no longer connect via SSH, etc.

I have been searching for a solution to this for months and only just now found one here: https://github.com/xbianonpi/xbian/issues/217. The solution is for xbian, but it worked for me on Raspbian.

The problem seems to be that the adapter has power management features enabled by default. This can be checked by running the command:

```
cat /sys/module/8192cu/parameters/rtw_power_mgnt
```

A value of 0 means disabled, 1 means min. power management, 2 means max. power management. To disable this, you need to create a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf
```

and add the following:

```
# Disable power management
options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0
```

Once you save the file and reboot your RPi, the WiFi should stay on indefinitely.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same thing is happening to be on xbian with 8192cu and power management is already set to 0. Somehow it still goes into coma...

Answer (score 3):

The preferred answer looks close to correct, but some additional comments in the original issue (https://github.com/xbianonpi/xbian/issues/217) would suggest an additional option is better:

`options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0`

in `/etc/modprobe.d/8192.conf`, as opposed to just `rtw_power_mgnt=0`.  Simply specifying that one option did not work for me, as the wifi still turned itself off.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was the screen saver. Disable with the following commands:

This turns off the screen saver:

```
xset s off
```

Disable other energy star features:

```
xset -dpms
```

This will **not** work in a remote SSH session

Answer (score 0):

## GDM

You can prevent GDM from suspending your computer by changing a value in `dconf-editor`. Note that I said `dconf-editor`, **not** `gconf-editor`.

```
$ dconf-editor
```

Now, you need to navigate to the `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` node. You should see a whole list of key-value pairs. Change the following keys to the following values.

- `sleep-inactive-ac-type` to *nothing*
- `sleep-inactive-battery-type` to *nothing*

## References

- [gdm suspends my machine, how can I stop it? - Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127740)

Comment: Where did he say he was using GDM?

Comment: @Jivings He didn't. I'm just providing an answer _in the case_ that he is using GDM.

Comment: Sorry, but -1 from me for an open-ended answer, with no sure fire way of knowing if it answers the question. You should have left a comment.

Comment: @Jivings How is this answer open-ended? I'm providing the GDM answer since we do not know more information?

Comment: Then you should ask for more information before answering.

Comment: I highly doubt that they will respond considering (1) they have no account on here, and (2) this question is about a week old. In this case it would still be best to provide an answer for future visitors.

Comment: I do have an account at stackoverflow and a few of the other stackexchange sites and I asked this question on superuser.stackexchange and then it got moved to raspberrypi.stackexchange. I guess that's why I got no notifications of replies. It got moved to a sub-site where I had no account, before anyone commented on it. Annoying.

Comment: Or maybe stackoverflow doesn't send email reminders... anyways, I finally saw the replies when I logged into stackoverflow.com today.

Comment: And finally, my raspberry pi is "headless" :-)

Comment: I think the actual problem is the WiFi itself and not the RPi going to sleep. See my answer for details.