# Raspberry Pi 3, wifi goes to sleep?

Tags: wifi, ssh, pi-3, openelec

I'm facing a similar issue to this one, [How do I disable suspend mode?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1384/how-do-i-disable-suspend-mode), except I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and am running OpenELEC 6.0.3.  When I leave it on without using it for awhile, I can no longer ssh to it or connect to it via samba.  I have to use it use again and then I'm able to connect to it (although occasionally I have to reboot in order to be able to ssh to it for some reason).

Is the wifi going into sleep mode when there is no traffic?  How can I disable it on the Pi 3?

Comment: Have you checked in the settings for something which gives you control over how long the Pi stays awake before going to sleep?

Comment: @DarthVader Yes I have and there are no power settings in OpenELEC

Answer (score 13):

To stop your wifi from go to sleep after idle for awhile, you need to disable its power management.

Edit file `/etc/network/interfaces`

Assume you Pi connect to network through `wlan0`. Add new line with `wireless-power off` right BELOW the line `iface wlan0 inet manual`

Save and reboot your Pi

run `iwconfig` now you should see `Power Management:off`

Comment: There is no /etc/network/interfaces nor iwconfig in OpenELEC though...

Comment: F.Y.I about OpenELEC, power saving has been disabled in the brcmfmac driver with RPi 4.4.5 linux kernel. You should use builds come with that kernel version

Comment: On Raspbian Stretch, there is no line "iface wlan0 inet manual" in the config file. If I add the option to the end and reboot, power management is still on. I used the command "iw wlan0 set power_save off" instead.

Answer (score 10):

Editing `/etc/network/interfaces` no longer works in Raspbian, as TSGames commented in the most upvoted answer.

Instead, you can use `/sbin/iw wlan0 get power_save` to read the current power save state, and `sudo /sbin/iw wlan0 set power_save off` to disable power state.

Since the `iw` command is not persistant, I added `/sbin/iw wlan0 set power_save off` to `/etc/rc.local` right before `exit 0` to have it set at startup (no need for `sudo` since rc.local already is run with admin rights).

Comment: I'm pretty certain that `iw` doesn't make any changes that persist after a reboot.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev You're absolutely right.  Good catch!  I've updated my answer.

Comment: When the question was asked, `/etc/network/interfaces` was working!

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

Octopi going to sleep fix.

The following did the trick for Octopi print server:

added the  **wireless-power off**  into the ipconfig.txt file since this file is called by the file at:  /etc/network/interfaces

No more sleeping octopi server!

Dana

Comment: Welcome -- but this is not a direct answer to the question.  Although it might be implied that the same answer will work generally, it's not clear that is the case.  And please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works ;)