# Screen blanking in X-Windows on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I'm on the similar project and issue as OP with screen-blanking (HDMI output), running a Raspbian Server 2.4:

- [Disable screen blanking in X-Windows on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian/2079#2079)

The standard user **pi** logs the session that auto-starts after a boot.

I have tried different approaches with no luck:

> .xinitrc

```
exec unclutter -root -noevents &
while sleep 5
do
        $HOME/websnurra-ng/websnurra-ng http://test.se
done

xset s off
xset s noexpose
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0
```

> /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

```
#!/bin/sh

# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#
# global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit (startx)

# invoke global X session script
. /etc/X11/Xsession
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0
```

> /etc/rc.local

```
setterm -blank 0 -cursor off
```

I have run the `xset` commands manually in the terminal and they execute correct viewing `xset q` just as they do when I boot the configuration files, although the screen still blanks out after some minutes.

I wanted to execute them as root, to see if that would make a difference, but end up with an error message:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
xset:  unable to open display "localhost:10.0"
```

Permissions:

> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -la

```
totalt 112
drwxr-xr-x 8 pi   pi    4096 okt 18 11:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 maj 25 18:35 ..
-rw------- 1 pi   pi    4184 okt 18 11:31 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi     220 maj 25 18:35 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi    3243 maj 25 18:35 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi   pi    4096 okt 15 14:53 .config
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi   pi    4096 jun 12 14:01 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi   pi    4096 okt  8 15:03 .gstreamer-0.10
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi    5781 feb  3  2013 ocr_pi.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi   pi     175 jun 12 16:00 pkgs.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 36740 jun 12 15:23 pkgs.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi     675 maj 25 18:35 .profile
drwxrwxr-x 2 pi   pi    4096 mar 10  2013 python_games
drwx------ 2 pi   pi    4096 okt 15 14:32 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi   pi    4096 okt 18 08:25 websnurra-ng
-rw------- 1 pi   pi      57 okt 18 11:39 .Xauthority
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi     210 okt 18 11:25 .xinitrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi     181 okt 17 09:40 .xinitrc.save
```

> pi@raspberrypi /etc/X11/xinit $ ls -la

```
totalt 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 okt  8 14:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 okt  8 14:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  246 okt 18 11:25 xinitrc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   56 okt 17 10:33 xserverrc
```

> pi@raspberrypi /etc $ ls -la rc.local

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 553 okt 18 13:40 rc.local
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a `xorg.conf` file with the following input and now it stays up:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor"
    Option "DPMS" "false"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "ServerLayout0"
    Option "BlankTime"  "0"
    Option "StandbyTime" "0"
    Option "SuspendTime" "0"
    Option "OffTime" "0"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did to disable screen blanking on my Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian.

Created a file on `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`:

```
# /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98x11-screen_blank
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
```

Be sure you have `xset` installed. The latest Raspbian already have it.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to put this out there so others searching for this very issue (screen blanking) could find this answer useful.

In /etc/xdg/lxsession there are two directories (LXDE and LXDE-pi)

**NOTE: This is if you are using the GUI (ex: in my case booting to terminal then using startx)**

Many forums are saying to edit the autostart file in LXDE but that did not resolve my issue. What did is to edit the autostart in LXDE-pi with the below.

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
#@xscreensaver -no-splash

@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
```

Then perform a reboot if needed.

The version currently using is:

Version: Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l

Hope someone finds this useful..