# How to wake a Volumio screen

Tags: ssh

I have Volumio installed on my Raspberry PI 2. However I've noticed the screen sleeps after about half an hour. Is there any way using SSH to wake the screen?

Comment: Edit in the output from `xset q | grep -A 2 "Screen Saver"`.

Comment: I don't know if you can wake the screen but you can prevent it from sleeping http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian?lq=1