# Pi connected Screen blackouts

Tags: raspbian, screen

I bought the Raspberry Pi 2 B, two days ago. I power it using a 5V 2A USB adapter. 
To the Pi, I have connected USB keyboard and Mouse(separate USBs), the Ethernet cable, HDMI to HDMI(44-inch LED-LCD TV). OS - Raspbian.

My screen(TV) blacks-out once every 30 seconds. I really dont know why.

Comment: How long does the screen "black out" for? How do you get the screen to display correctly again?

Comment: Just for 1 or 2 second. Then the display comes back up.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions -- I'd be surprised if the problem is to do with the first one, but try it first.

1. Have a look at the [suggestions here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/2079/5538) about disabling screen blanking. The reason I'd be surprised if this was it is every 30 seconds seems daft, but again, this is simple to try.  You do not actually need to add those to an `initrc` file, you can first try them straight on the command line and they should take immediate effect, but you may have to install `xset` first, as per the comments.
2. Have a look at the [HDMI boot settings documented here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi-mode-options); they are added to `/boot/config.txt` (if you are unaware of this file, read that page from the beginning).  This is more of a hassle because you have to reboot.  Try the `hdmi_safe=1` option first.  If it works, look at the list of things this implicitly includes, and try with just the first three:

   ```
   hdmi_force_hotplug=1
   hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
   config_hdmi_boost=4
   ```

   If that works, try removing the middle (`ignore_edid`) one.  If one of these combinations works, you are good to go.

Comment: I think option 2 is a good suggestion.  It sounds, to me, like the TV isn't quite getting the signal it needs to stay awake.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact hdmi_safe=1 implies ALL of these:

`hdmi_force_hotplug=1
    hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
    config_hdmi_boost=4
    hdmi_group=2
    hdmi_mode=4
    disable_overscan=0
    overscan_left=24
    overscan_right=24
    overscan_top=24
    overscan_bottom=24`

`hdmi_safe=1` worked for me but the 3 metioned by @goldilocks did not.

You can try and tweak the others the same way if the first 3 don't do the trick.
The 5 for overscan parameters did nothing but give me the black bars around the image, but the `hdmi_mode` did.

For `hdmi_mode` I tried a ton of different values listed in the documentation (specifically **[here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt/video.md)**) and ended up using `hdmi_mode=5` (which is 1080i/60Hz).

Since I'm on a TV I also set `hdmi_group=1`.

Good luck!