# How to avoid screen turning off

Tags: screen-saver

I am using a Raspberry Pi connected to a TV (monitor) to show some information; it is inactive most of the time. My problem is that the screen turns off every five minutes.

This is what I tried with no success:

1. Set blank time and power down time as follows in `/etc/kbd/config`

   BLANK_TIME=0
   POWERDOWN_TIME=0
2. Added these lines to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`

   @xset s noblank
   @xset s off
   @xset -dpms
3. Added these lines to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`

   xset s off
   xset -dpms
   xset s noblank

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian/2079#2079

Comment: for my raspbian/jessie based Pi the @xset lines are in  ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart and work correctly

Comment: Like @rob said, you need to add those lines to `LXDE-pi/autostart` not `LXDE/autostart`

Comment: Thanks rob, I moved those lines to LXDE-pi and it is working fine now. If you want to make your comment an answer I will be glad to accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paths seem to have changed in the Jessie Raspbian.

Try putting the

```
@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
```

lines in the **~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart** file not the **LXDE/autostart**