# How to disable Screensaver on Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: raspbian-jessie

how can I disable the Screensaver on Raspbian Jessie?
I tried putting this into .xinitrc

```
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
```

but it doesn't work for me

Comment: which .xinitrc. The one in etc/... or in the Pi's home directory?

Comment: I tried this ~/.config/autostart/.xinitrc
and this ~/.xinitrc 
 --- x11-xserver-utils is installed

Comment: @YannikMündler What kind of screensaver? The fancy drawing thing or the screen-going-off thing?

Comment: Take a look at this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian/2079#2079

Comment: Yes this screen-going-off thing   tried it in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc , still doesn't work

Comment: when I run xset -q i get this response
xset:  unable to open display ""

Comment: Try @DerDirektor answer it worked for me where the others including mine did not, and let me know if that worked

Comment: FYI the error about unable to open display - probably results because you are either at the terminal or SSH prompt. Second I am assuming that after making these changes you are rebooting.

Comment: Also didn't work, only solution was from Miles Hayler, to install screensaver and disable it from within the screensaver, nevertheless I appreciate your help

Comment: @Yannik Mündler Add `consoleblank=0` to the end of `/boot/cmdline.txt`

Comment: In the GUI, just set it to No Screensaver.