# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ goes to black screen after a short while of inactivity

Tags: hdmi, display

It ranges between 10 to 30 minutes. It is attached to a TV via HDMI. The monitor will go black. Moving the mouse of tapping the keyboard of the Raspberry Pi will "wake up" the screen pretty quickly.

It is running Raspbian OS as a standard image. The resolution is set to CEA mode 32 1920x1080p.

How do I stop it going to sleep? It is for a monitoring dashboard which would ideally run without interference :-)

Comment: Nice, snarky response, but sure, I added the question which you (hopefully) already realized what was :-)

Comment: sorry about that, we get too many like that .... you know the kind "how come it is dark every time the power goes out" ... lol

Comment: No worries. I guess there's a small concern of variance here too. It doesn't go black after X minutes, it seems to vary between 10-30 minutes mostly, and yesterday, perhaps 1-2 hours. It's fairly weird.

Comment: found this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian ....... also, your monitor may have a built in screen saver

Comment: The first answer there worked, it would appear! Thank you.

Comment: Disregard that. It went out again after about ~40min :-(

Comment: start looking at the logs ....  maybe something is occurring at the time that the screen blanks out

Comment: Can you elaborate which logs?