# Prevent screen from going blank for kiosk

Tags: debian, xorg, display

I should start off by saying I am fairly new to Linux. I want my pi to scroll through pictures in Image Viewer and never sleep. I've followed these instructions from [another question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-do-i-prevent-the-screen-from-going-blank) to try to fix the sleeping problem.

```
apt-get install x11-xserver-utils 

 Now open up your ~/.xinitrc file
(if you don't have one then create it) and enter this:

xset s off         # don't activate screensaver 
xset -dpms         # disable DPMS (Energy Star) features. 
xset s noblank     # don't blank the video device

exec /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager      # start lxde
```

I didn't have the .xinitrc file in my home directory so I created one. It hasn't seemed to make a difference. I also have a .Xauthority file in /home/pi and have tried renaming it but it creates a new .Xauthority file.

Comment: Sure the file is located at `~/.xinitrc` and you have `xset` installed?

Comment: `x11-xserver-utils is already the newest version.` and .xinitrc is in the /home/pi directory

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find what directory the .xinitrc file should be created in to stop the screen saver from activating?

Comment: How are you starting X? .Xauthority is autogenerated and not relevant here, I think. You could also try calling your session script `~/.xsession`. I believe xinit is a relic and so is its .xinitrc. It is used by startx, though. Login managers might or might not ignore it. I think I've also seen .xclients and don't ask me about CDE. Either way, .xsession and .xsession-errors are my preference. You can grep -r for mention of those files in scripts in /etc/X11. Also, startx is probably a script that you can read to see exactly what it does.

Comment: Have you tested the `xset` commands in an already running X and do they make a difference? It's not altogether impossible that bare X blanking is broken in your server version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and use the following `xserver-command`:

```
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms
```

This worked for me at least.