# Raspberry Pi + Raspbian, "The screen saver strikes again"

Tags: screen-saver

Thanks to plenty of clear and sufficient advices about getting rid off 'screen saver', I can say I am pretty experienced in that field (at least theoretically)... However I did not solve the problem yet!

The thing is, that [this solution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/753/3996) (which seems to be the best one) after few moments of waiting, gives me a black&white picture - a perfect one to make sb feel dizzy. It looks like some kind of repeatable, deformed-checker pattern.

Poking the mouse or pressing any key makes it disappear and recovers the normal screen.

Could you please give me any hints to check out what actually went wrong?

I am running the latest distribution of Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 2.0. In the background there are an Apache, FTP and MySQL servers running and also Chromium in the kiosk mode.

Cheers

Comment: Did you make these entries in the global config file in /etc or in your home directory /home/pi?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried both ways, but only second one brought me to any noticeable change - I mean appearance of psychedelic checkers in place of normal black screen.

Comment: To be clear you have tried adding the following 3 lines (without the number and right parenthesis) lines to your /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc file:  1) xset s off  2) xset -dpms  3) xset s noblank The first specifically disables the screen saver

Answer (score 2):

I end up with this solution - it is rather an work-around, but at least it does the job.

You need to create two files. First one, i.e. **disableSS.desktop**:

```
#!/bin/bash
[Desktop Entry]
Name=disableSS
Exec=sh /home/user/disableSS.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

It basically just runs a shell script from the defined path. It should be placed in your **/home/user/.config/autostart/** folder.

And the second one, **disableSS.sh**:

```
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
setterm -blank 0
```

Those lines prevent the screen from blanking, but just temporarily (for actual session). This is the reason of wrapping them into a script and launching them with every Raspbian start. Place the 2nd file in your **/home/user/** folder.

Again: I cannot guarantee this solution is the best one, but it works fine for me.

**After implementing above, the issues with screen never occurred again.**

Cheers