# Power on display results in blank screen

Tags: power, display, screen

I'm currently trying to write a simple script that turns on and off my monitor connected to the rpi via hdmi-to-dvi cable.

I can turn off the monitor without issue using:

```
tvservice -o
```

However when I use `tvservice -p` the monitor will wake but it will be a blank screen (Monitor is on but is black and keeps try to switch between analog/digital to find a signal.)

I've changed the `/boot/config.txt` to:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

I've also [disabled screen blanking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-do-i-prevent-the-screen-from-going-blank) to no avail.

How can I power on my monitor without it resulting in blank screen?

Comment: have you tried this after doing the tvservice -p?:
xset dpms force on

Comment: This worked. If you make the comment an answer i'll accept it. It's also worth mentioning that running these commands via ssh won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the following commands(you should be able to run this via ssh if you export display):

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
tvservice -p
xset dpms force on
#redo the no-sleep commands if the screen had no sleep enabled before
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank
```

It should get your screen back on