# Prevent Pi from sleeping

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config

I am working on a project similar to the one at http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Wall-Mounted-Google-Calendar/?ALLSTEPS

Similarly, I need my pi to stay on constantly. I have the regular Raspbian OS installed and I am using Iceweasel browser to run a web application all day.

I have tried every single one of these suggestions from this link http://www.bitpi.co/2015/02/14/prevent-raspberry-pi-from-sleeping/

Yet the pi fails to stay on longer than 10 minutes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just as a side-comment - I picked up an [Azpen A745 android tablet](http://www.microcenter.com/product/448360/A745_Tablet) last weekend for $30 bucks at Microcenter - and it has a Google Calendar. In a few easy steps you can disable screen dimming/sleep in Android and you have a wallmounted Google Calendar solution :) Display viewing angle is not fantastic, but this saves you a lot of work - unless you are of course committed to using the rPi for this :). I use mine as a terminal for [RuneAudio](http://www.runeaudio.com/) - I velcroed it to the wall.

Comment: Thanks @PhilB. but I am not running Google Calendar. Im running a web application I built and also its on 40 inch screen. But thank you for introducing me to RuneAudio ! Can't wait to try that out

Comment: Thanks @Huygens I tried that one as well. I completely reinstalled the OS and the solution below worked

Comment: You can always install gnome-utils and gain control over the screensaver via the preferences menu.  Screen banking is easy to control there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it's not working since the last option mentioned in that post (lightdm configuration - Xsession blanking) worked pretty good for me.

Here is the easiest way for you.

Install xscreensaver by "sudo apt-get install xscreensaver"

Once installed, go to Rpi's desktop "Menu" (left top corner) [I'm assuming that you're running a raspbian?]

Go to preference ---> screensaver.

You will see a screen saver main menu. In mode : section, select "disable screensaver" and close.

Reboot Rpi. It should work now.

====================================

Also have a look at links below:

[Disable screen blanking in X-Windows on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian)

[How do I prevent the screen from going blank?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-do-i-prevent-the-screen-from-going-blank)

Hope it helps.