# Screen going blank after a while

Tags: screen

When using the Raspberry Pi 3 to run a presentation in Libre Office,
the screen goes blank after a while. My questions:

1. Is there a file that I can configure/set the screen active constantly?
2. Where are these files located? (in the root? home?)
3. Will the changes take effect without rebooting the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: The screen goes blank and what next? You press a key and the display is active again, or you need to reboot, or what?

Comment: Have you seen this https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry+pi+change+screen+timeout

Comment: @elefantPhace please remember the first rule of SO is to be nice. Also, please remember we were all noobs once.

Comment: @ppumkin given your follow up comment I understand what you were saying but the original comment did not come off that way.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open up `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` using your favorite text editor.
2. Look for the line `#xserver-command=X`. Change it to `xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms`

   - It should be at line 87 if things don't change.
3. Save and reboot.

[Source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51687/59271)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to install gnome-system-tools - then you will have a menu, Preferences, Screensaver program that can help you do those settings in the GUI.

Answer (score -2):

Run

```
sudo nano etc/kbd/config
```

and try changing `BLANK_TIME` to `0` and `POWERDOWN_TIME` to `0`.

Save the file and then restart the process by typing

```
sudo /etc/init.d/kbd restart
```

Comment: "restart the file"? What does that mean?

Comment: @Bex I think he means to restart the process and/or service