# Turn off screen saver

Tags: raspbian

I would like to either turn off the screen saver or increase the time before it activates.  I can't seem to find a Utilities folder?

Comment: Have you tried [http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian) or [http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-do-i-prevent-the-screen-from-going-blank](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-do-i-prevent-the-screen-from-going-blank)?