# How do you turn off the screensaver in Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, screen-saver

Simple question: how do you turn off the d*mn screen saver in Raspbian for Pi 3 Model B? It keeps popping up even if I leave Chromium looping a video in Kiosk mode. I tried the solution from [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/23116/66895), but it does nothing to stop the screensaver from showing.

Answer (score 3):

You should try using **xscreensaver**. You can easily disable screen saver using **xscreensaver-demo**, which will prompt a simple GUI config. In the **Display Modes** tab, you should see a drop-down list named **Mode**. From there select **Disable Screen Saver** and that should do the trick.

You don't have to use the graphical interface, here is a link to the manual if you are interested in looking at specific terminal commands etc: https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html

Comment: This disabled the screensaver, but the screen still turned to black.

Comment: You should check the Advanced tab and look for Display Power Management. I think you want to **de**select both Power Management Enabled and Quick Power-off in Blank Mode.

Comment: I have spent countless evenings scouring the Internet for a solution to the blank screen problem, none work. This finally does (FWIW, Pi 3, Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch) Raspberry Pi reference 2017-11-29)