# Configure Raspberry pi to run my application before GUI Desktop

Tags: python, boot, qt, startx

I have created an application through Python that has library dependencies on Qt4, pyqt4, pyqtgraph etc. This application is based on Raspberry Pi, I have developed and finished it on the platform.

I want to configure Raspberry Pi to only run that one single application. When I power the Raspberry Pi, it should not go to desktop but run the application (eventually only use necessary packages,library etc).

I have been looking around on different forums on how people do it, but it's not what I'm exactly looking for. There are also different solutions but it's just a bit confusing, that's why I'm here asking for advice/tips on how to implement that.

So far I've tried sudo /etc/profile and at the end of that file I call python3 /home/pi/test.py where i eexecute my application. But I get X cannot connect Server error and Virtual Keyboard Florence is not really registering the button pressed.

Comment: Starting an graphical application without using a desktop program isn't really specific to Raspberry Pi. I suggest you better ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com. You may get better answers.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is a "# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))" **NOT** for running programs.

Comment: If you use Raspbian Buster Light that comes without a GUI can you start your application from the command line? Or do you need the X Server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip loading the desktop, I would suggest not using the `.xinitrc` route, but replace loading the session with your own program.

Create `~/.xsessionrc` with one line

```bsh
STARTUP=
```

Create `~/.Xsession` with whatever you want to start. You might want to throw in a few lines to avoid screen blanking and screen savers:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
xset s off                  # don't activate screensaver
xset -dpms                  # disable DPMS (Energy Star) features.
xset s noblank              # don't blank the video device
python3 /home/pi/test.py    # now start your script
```

To use `xset`, you will have to install `x11-xserver-utils` first:

```
sudo apt install x11-xserver-utils
```

This worked for me on a Pi Zero W with Debian Stretch and a Python TkInter GUI.

Sources: [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/79815), [stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-do-i-prevent-the-screen-from-going-blank/753#753)

Comment: It's not working...The application doesn't start and I just continue to desktop.

Comment: what is your debian version? try `cat /etc/os-release`. is your application running when launched from the commandline?

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use LightDM, the correct file to start your GUI apps before the desktop environment starts is `/etc/lightdm/Xsession`. If you want to configure startup differently for each user, you typically put there a line

```
[ -f ~/.xprofile ] && . ~/.xprofile
```

and then configure the startup for a given user by editing their `~/.xprofile`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing a script from `/etc/profile`, it is running in a terminal context, not a display context.

To run a script whenever the window manager initializes, edit your `~/.xinitrc`, and add your script.

For example `nano ~/.xinitrc`, and add `python3 /home/pi/test.py`.

Comment: Didn't work either. I just get to the desktop..